# How to test whether router blocks WOL

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to setup a basic remote WOL to my PC. The WOL on itself is working when I'm on the same network. I've added the address as a port forward with port set as port 9. I have other tools which use other port forwarded ports which are all running fine.

What is the best way to check/debug if your router is blocking the WOL request? I've tried sniffing the port with WireShark but could not view anything being received on that specific port.

Comment: Depends on how you send the WOL. If the PC is asleep it won't answer ARP requests. that leaves broadcasts or permanent ARP assigned on the router for the PC to receive the WOL packet. The router won't either do broadcasts from anything received from remote. So in the end, the router has to specifically participate in WOL, not just not block it.

Comment: I'm sending the WOL from the depicus WOL website. By "specifically participate in WOL" you mean portforward AND allow for such a packet to be forwarded? If my router blocks the WOL I won't be able to see that package with WireShark coming in and not making it past my router I guess?

Comment: As long a the target system (the PC) is awake, you should see such packet. I was saying that once you see it (and hence solve one part of your question), this won't mean the PC will always be woken up in the end, because of my previous comment.